# privoxy and tor in windows 503 forwarding failure

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, privoxy

I am currently trying to use privoxy with tor. I have done the following.

Installed Tor Browser. From command line run: tor -f .\torrc-defaults
Netstat -a: shows 127.0.0.1 port 9150 and 9151.

Installed privoxy 
forward-socks5t   /               127.0.0.1:9150 .

On windows 10 allowed incoming and outgoing connections to 8118, 9150 and 9151.

Set proxy on my browser to 127.0.0.1 port 8118

After all of this I receive http 503 error forwarding failure

Comment: Is there a requirement for privoxy? It seems superfluous? Does setting the browser to use Tor's SOCKSPort work? What does privoxy's log say?

Answer (score 0):

Try this Tor+Privoxy bundle: https://www.praetor.space/downloads
You can see what configuration they use.